# Чтение из файла и работа со строками

Tags: c++

Народ, помогите, пожалуйста разобраться новичку в программировании на С++ со следующей задачкой:

**Дан файл, содержащий текст на русском языке (не более 50 строк). В алфавитном по-рядке вывести все звонкие согласные, которые входят в каждое нечетное слово и не входят ни в одно четное слово.**

Ниже привожу код. Программа написана в Visual Studio (теоретически, может не скомпилироваться в других средах). Программа открывает исходный файл, выводит его на экран, но ничего не делает со строками, а выдает пустую строку вместо вывода результата. Где, в чем, какая ошибка, как и на что переправить код, чтобы программа заработала? Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    const std::string voiced = "бвгдзлмнр";

    std::vector<std::string> not_even_words;
    std::vector<std::string> even_words;
    std::set<char> voiced_consonants;
    std::string buf;
    std::string word;
    std::istringstream isstr;
    size_t i = 0;

    std::ifstream file("Input.txt");
    while (true)
    {
        std::string str;
        file>>str;

        if (!file.eof())
            std::cout<<str<<std::endl;

        else
            break;
    }

    std::getline(file, buf);
    char * s = new char [buf.length() + 1];
    strcpy_s(s, buf.length() + 1, buf.c_str());
    OemToCharA(s, s);
    buf = s;
    delete[] s;
    isstr.str(buf);

    while (isstr >> word) {
        if (++i & 1)
            not_even_words.push_back(word);
        else
            even_words.push_back(word);
    }

    std::for_each(not_even_words.begin(), not_even_words.end(), [&](std::string str) -> void
    {
        std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](char c) -> void
        {
            if (voiced.find(c) != std::string::npos && isalpha((unsigned char)c)) {
                bool ins = true;
                std::for_each(not_even_words.begin(), not_even_words.end(), [c, &ins](std::string s) -> void
                {
                    if (s.find(c) == std::string::npos)
                        ins = false;
                });
                if (ins)
                    voiced_consonants.insert(c);
            }
        });
    });

    std::for_each(even_words.begin(), even_words.end(), [&](std::string str) -> void
    {
        std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](char c) -> void
        {
            if (std::binary_search(voiced_consonants.begin(), voiced_consonants.end(), c))
                voiced_consonants.erase(c);
        });
    });

    std::copy(
        voiced_consonants.begin(),
        voiced_consonants.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Многовато std:: кода для новичка

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком много букаф для такого задания. Я не вчитывался, как и предыдущие комментаторы, потому как проще написать свою реализацию :) Из вопроса не понятно, нужно ли выводить звонкие согласные столько раз, сколько они встретились в тексте или достаточно, просто вывести их по одному разу. Но это легко в коде одно на другое правится. Для теста данные можно читать из строки, а не из файла. Для этого заремаркируйте те строки, где в конце '///' и разремаркируйте те, где вначале '///'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //заполните заглавными буквами при необходимости
    std::map<std::string, int>voiced;
    voiced["б"]=0; voiced["в"]=0; voiced["г"]=0;
    voiced["д"]=0; voiced["з"]=0; voiced["л"]=0;
    voiced["м"]=0; voiced["н"]=0; voiced["р"]=0;
    voiced["ж"]=0; voiced["й"]=0;

    std::string even, odd, buf;
    std::ifstream file("Input.txt");///
    ///std::string file = "Дан файл, содержащий текст на русском языке (не более 50 строк).";
    ///std::istringstream ist(file);

    bool bEven = false;
    ///while (ist>>buf)
    while (file>>buf) ///
    {
        if(!bEven)
        {
            odd+=buf;
            bEven = true;
        }
        else
        {
            even+=buf;
            bEven = false;
        }
    }
    file.close(); ///

    for(auto&x:voiced)
    {
        if(even.find(x.first)!=std::string::npos)x.second=2;
        if(odd.find(x.first)!=std::string::npos)x.second=1;
    }

    /*std::map<std::string, int>::iterator x = voiced.begin();
    while(x!=voiced.end())
    {
        if(even.find(x->first)!=std::string::npos)x->second=2;
        if(odd.find(x->first)!=std::string::npos)x->second=1;
        x++;
    }*/

    //у меня работает и с этой локалью и без нее. У себя пропишите ту, которая установлена у Вас. Хотя, как я понимаю, для Вас это и не должно иметь значения - главное сам алгоритм, а не вывод в какой-то определенной кодировке.
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.UTF-8")); 
    for(auto&x:voiced)
    if(x.second==2) std::cout << x.first;

    /*x = voiced.begin();
    while(x!=voiced.end())
    {
        if(x->second==2) std::cout << x->first;
        x++;
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Max ZS, спасибо за Ваш вариант, который гораздо более компактный, чем мой. Но у меня VS не компилит предложенный Вами код и выдает ошибку: "x: символ, тип которого содержит спецификатор "auto" должен иметь инициализатор". Ведь действительно Х не инициализирован. Где в коде и какую инициализацию вставить?

Comment: @DMP Это написано на C++. И VS компилит этот код. Это можно проверить на [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). Единственный ньюанс, это если у Вас компилятор 2010 и древнее. Потому как уже давно априори стандартом считается C++11, а на данный момент в природе уже существует стандарт C++17. Но, по-моему, даже в VS2010 auto поддерживалось. Хотя вовсе не проблематично переписать эти циклы без auto.

Comment: Вы были правы. Компилятор у меня действительно был 2010. Поставил свежий. Теперь все компилируется, НО программа не выдает результат...(( Просто выводит "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу" без каких-либо данных. Пробовал и первоначальный код, и с изменением циклов для избавления от auto, ничего не помогает... P.S. Чтение делаю из файла т.е. все как в первоначальном коде.

Comment: @DMP А строка для теста в файле такая же как и в коде? А указанная локаль такая же как на Вашей машине? А не полная ясность задания, озвученная мной в ответе, будет уточнена? Может Вы ожидаете какого-то конкретного результата при конкретных данных?

Comment: Строки в файле такие же как для теста в коде - обычные предложения, начинающиеся с заглавной буквы и оканчивающиеся точкой. Локаль UTF-8. Звонкие согласные выводить столько раз, сколько они встретились в тексте.

Comment: @DMP По шагам... 1) Перейдите по ссылке и проверьте, работает ли код [http://ideone.com/yxIGZC](http://ideone.com/yxIGZC) ? 2) Далее скопируйте код и вставьте его на этой странице (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) . Также проверьте работает ли код. 3) Скопируйте код в свою программу и проверьте, работает ли он у Вас. 4) Все что пишет Вам компьютер в ответ - читайте. Если не заработало и написало разные ругательства - поведайте о них мне.

Comment: Все сделал по пунктам. Все везде работает. А причина по которой программа не давала никакого результата - это то, что уникальных звонких согласных, которые не встречаются ни в одном четном слове (по условию задания) просто нет)) Я построчно (через чтение из файла) прогнал текст и все нужные согласные программа выводит. ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ВАМ ЗА ПОМОЩЬ!

Comment: @DMP в данном примере в строе есть одна буква - "м". Я предлагал (см. ответ) тестировать, производя чтение именно из строки. Это сразу снимало бы ряд вопросов. Но Вы выбрали другой путь... Также В комментариях я спрашивал: "А строка для теста в файле такая же как и в коде?". И еще там же я спрашивал: "Может Вы ожидаете какого-то конкретного результата при конкретных данных?" Обратите внимание на то, что последний приведенный код для теста видоизменен согласно уточненному условию задачи.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае если файл не открылся (например, нет его - получается бесконечный цикл).
Попробуйте так:

```
std::ifstream file("d:/Input.txt",std::ios_base::in);
file.imbue(std::locale("rus_rus.1251"));
while (!file.eof() && file.good())
{   
    std::string str;     
    file>>str;
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
};
```

Кстати, поcле использования поток необходимо закрыть
file.close();

P.S.: правильнее будет так :

```
std::ifstream file("d:/Input.txt",std::ios_base::in);
file.imbue(std::locale("rus_rus.1251"));
std::string str;
bool flipflop = 1;
while (file>>str)
{     
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    if (flipflop)  odd_words.push_back(str);
    else even_words.push_back(str);
    flipflop=!flipflop;
};
file.close();
std::cout << std::endl << "Чётные~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << std::endl;
for (it1 = even_words.begin();it1 < even_words.end();it1++)
    std::cout << *it1 << std::endl;

std::cout << std::endl << "Нечётные~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << std::endl;
for (it1 = odd_words.begin();it1 < odd_words.end();it1++)
    std::cout << *it1 << std::endl;
```

Смысла в использовании OemToChar не вижу если честно.

Comment: Проблемы у автора начинаются явно после этих строк, так что Ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос. Кроме того, Вы также могли показать автору, что так строки читать нельзя — если в строке буде пробел, до из файла будет прочитана лишь часть строки.

Comment: Точно, поторопился я. Но так ли нужен автору OemToCharA ? Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Я не вчитывался в код, дальше первых строчек, поэтому не могу сказать, что там нужно, а что нет :)